# Query match pattern tokeniser

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Say we have a search query **Vacuum cleaner WSP 6666 C 22 C 2 KW rubber** which we want to match against our index. Of of the indexed products is:

```
...
"categories": [
    "Vacuum cleaner",
    "Blender",
],
"modelnumbers": [
    "WSP 6666 C 22 C 2 KW",
    "ABST 23",
    "2h28f7h2i3f",
]
```

Now I want to match on both category as modelnumber

```
{
  "query": {
      "function_score": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "Vacuum cleaner WSP 6666 C 22 C 2 KW rubber",
                  "default_operator": "OR",
                  "default_field": "categories",
                  "boost": "10"
                }
              },
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "Vacuum cleaner WSP 6666 C 22 C 2 KW rubber",
                  "default_operator": "OR",
                  "default_field": "modelnumbers",
                  "boost": "10"
                }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

This shows me the correct result. However now it matches on all of the following:

- Vacuum
- cleaner
- WSP
- 666666
- C
- 22
- C
- 2
- KW

Is there a possible way with tokenisers which makes it possible it only finds matches?:

- Vacuum cleaner
- WSP 6666 C 22 C 2 KW

As you can see not all regexes have the same format, so there is no possibility to use the regex tokeniser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is to index the data using (edge-)ngrams. But before doing this, you might want to try using a `multi_match` query that matches on the fields that you care about:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Vacuum cleaner WSP 6666 C 22 C 2 KW rubber",
      "fields": [
        "categories",
        "modelnumbers"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow Val's suggestions, and also take a look at the cross_fields multi-match query. You can later improve your query with a DisMax or a Bool Query (The DisMax query is actually a bool query).